# Spark SQL distinct and Scala distinct give different counts, in spite of same data input data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

> val apple1=spark.sql("select count(distinct *) from apple1 where data1_ts =201804").show

10871344

> apple1.filter(col("data1_ts") === "201804").distinct.count

20573671

any idea both are using distinct on a table in s3,and selecting a particular directory, but gives different values?

Comment: try this in sql `select distinct(count( * )) from apple1 where data1_ts =201804"`

Comment: Is the data being continuously loaded? S3 has latency issues in some cases.

Comment: The notion of the question based yogesh is escaping me.

Comment: distinct count(*) is same as count(*) @Yogesh

Comment: Can you show code preceding second statement pls?

Comment: `code` val apple1=spark.read.parquet("s3://tv_main//tv_sub/")